# I can't use command "start" in git bash

Tags: git, shell, command-line

When I type "start" to open up a .txt file, it returns `/usr/bin/start: line 8: No such file or directory`

I guess it returns my whole path but idk.

I have tried adding `C:\Windows\System32` to path but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you try running the following command within your git bash to find the start binary? `where start`
(And then post the paths, if any, here?)

Comment: @H.Syd yes, it returns: `D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\start`

Comment: What is `start` supposed to do? That's not a binary that's generally available on Linux systems. What is "line 8"? If you want to open a text file, open an editor (or use `cat` or `less` if you only want to view its content)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @knittl its supposed to open the .txt file in notepad. I am learning how to use git bash, the thing is that "start" works on my other computer but not on my main.

Comment: @EnriqueMilo Is `/c/WINDOWS/system32` in your Path variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git bash, `/usr/bin/start` is a shell script that invokes `"$COMSPEC" //c start "${@//&/^&}"`. If invoked with a `.txt` file as an argument. You can examine the file itself; it's an 8-line text file.

It's specific to git bash under Windows.  It's a way to provide the equivalent of the `cmd.exe` `START` command, or double-clicking on a Windows icon, in a Unix-like environment. (Cygwin and WSL, which are also Unix-like environments under Windows, don't provide the same thing; Cygwin has `cygstart`, and WSL is more isolated from the Windows environment.)

If you invoke it as `start foo.txt`, it should invoke your default handler for `*.txt` files, determined by your Windows settings. That might be Notepad by default, but perhaps you've configured it to be some other editor.

Try `echo "$COMSPEC"`. The result should be `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`. The `/usr/bin/start` script seems to be complaining that the command that `$COMSPEC` expands to does not exist; either `$COMSPEC` has been changed, or `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` is unavailable (the latter could indicate a damaged Windows system).

If you type `"$COMSPEC"` (with the double quotes) at the git bash prompt, it should give you a Windows `cmd` prompt; if so, you can leave it by typing `exit`.

```
$ type -a start
start is /usr/bin/start
start is /bin/start
start is /usr/bin/start
$ cat /usr/bin/start
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright (C) 2014, Alexey Pavlov
#   mailto:alexpux@gmail.com
# This file is part of Minimal SYStem version 2.
#   https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/
# File: start

"$COMSPEC" //c start "${@//&/^&}"
$ echo "$COMSPEC"
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
$ "$COMSPEC"
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\username>exit
exit
$
```

Comment: really helpful now i understand better, but `echo "$COMSPEC"` doesn't return `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` the result is my whole path variable for some reason, and when i type `"$COMSPEC"` returns my whole path again and that there's no such file or directory. Also, `cat /usr/bin/start` is the same 8 line text file as yours. Is my system damaged then?

Comment: @EnriqueMilo I don't know whether your system is damaged, but your environment is. Launch `cmd` and type `echo %COMSPEC%`; do you get the same thing? COMSPEC should be just your command line interpreter, *not* your entire search path. I have no idea how your `COMSPEC` setting was corrupted, or what else might have been stepped on. Did you do something in settings?

Comment: sadly it does return the same thing `C:\Python312\Scripts\;C:\Python312\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C...` :(. I don't remember changing anything

Comment: @EnriqueMilo You can go into Windows settings and fix the value of COMSPEC. (Google for how to do that if necessary.) But again, we don't know what else might be messed up or how it happened. There are probably better and more general ways to fix a damaged environment on a Windows system, but I don't know what they are; that might be a question for [su]. (Run `set` from a `cmd` prompt to see your environment variable settings.)

Comment: thanks, i'll be checking that out, hopefully I find whats wrong, have a good one.